# I need to create a timer that has hour, mins, and seconds

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I currently have code that can display mins and seconds.
But the problem I'm facing is that when the mins gets to 60, it counts up to 61 and beyond.

How can I add the hours?

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt{

        totalTime += dt;
        currentTime = (int)totalTime;
    if (myTime < currentTime)
{
    myTime = currentTime;
    [countUpTimer setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", myTime/60, myTime%60]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[countUpTimer setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", myTime/3600, (myTime/60)%60, myTime%60]];
```